# Apple TensorFlow fork and Pandas clash on M1 chip

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, apple-m1

anyone knows how to install Pandas (and actually import), NOT under Rosetta to be able to use Apple's forked TensorFlow to use in native M1 mode?
I can only do one or the other, whereas I need both.
If I install under Rosetta TF won't work.
If I install Apple's TF for M1, Pandas won't install.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope Xcode Command Line Tools is already installed. If not, please install it then follow the steps.

**Step 1:miniforge**

Install miniforge for arm64 (Apple Silicon) from [miniforge GitHub](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge).
Miniforge enables installing python packages natively compiled for Apple Silicon.

**Step 2: Download ATF 2.4**

Then Download TensorFlow 2.4 from [Apple GitHub](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos), untar it but don’t install it by using the provided script. Go under the `arm64` directory:

**Step 3: create Conda environment**

*Don’t forget to open a new session or to source your *.zshrc* after miniforge install and before going through this step.*

Create an empty Conda environment, then activate it and install python 3.8 (as required for ATF 2.4) and all the needed packages. Please note numpy is unnecessary here as pandas already install it, but it will be overwritten in the last step with the version provided by Apple.

```
conda create --name mytf
conda activate mytf
conda install -y python==3.8.6
conda install -y pandas matplotlib scikit-learn jupyterlab
```

**Step 4: install all the ATF 2.4 packages**

Now manually install ATF 2.4 packages under your Conda environment.

Please note the following instruction corresponds to the second ATF 2.4 release, namely 0.1 alpha 1. Any new release can require a different process, you will be able to adapt it by checking install_venv.sh content.

```
# Install specific pip version and some other base packages
pip install --force pip==20.2.4 wheel setuptools cached-property six
# Install all the packages provided by Apple but TensorFlow
pip install --upgrade --no-dependencies --force numpy-1.18.5-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl grpcio-1.33.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl h5py-2.10.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl tensorflow_addons-0.11.2+mlcompute-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
# Install additional packages
pip install absl-py astunparse flatbuffers gast google_pasta keras_preprocessing opt_einsum protobuf tensorflow_estimator termcolor typing_extensions wrapt wheel tensorboard typeguard
# Install TensorFlow
pip install --upgrade --force --no-dependencies tensorflow_macos-0.1a1-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl
```